# Why does this Boost.Spirit x3 rule parse correctly with angle brackets, but incorrectly with quotes?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

The program  below tries to parse C++ header include strings, such as `"my/file.hpp"` and `<my/file.hpp>`. For reasons I don't understand, my code fails to parse the `"` headers. Is this a bug in Spirit, or am I missing something obvious?

```
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

int main() {

    auto header_name_brackets = '<' >> *(~char_('>')) >> '>';
    auto header_name_quotes   = '"' >> *(~char_('>')) >> '"'; 

    {
        auto s = std::string{"<my/file.hpp>"};
        std::string parsed;
        assert(phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), header_name_brackets, space, parsed));
    }

    {
        auto s = std::string{"\"my/file.hpp\""};
        std::string parsed;
        // this assert fails, but I don't know why.
        assert(phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), header_name_quotes, space, parsed));
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really knowing Boost Spirit, but shouldn't `~char_('>')` be `~char_('"')` for the quoted "header name"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

int main() {

    auto header_name_brackets = '<' >> *(~char_('>')) >> '>';
    auto header_name_quotes   = '"' >> *(~char_('"')) >> '"'; 

    {
        auto s = std::string{"<my/file.hpp>"};
        std::string parsed;
        assert(phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), header_name_brackets, space, parsed));
    }

    {
        auto s = std::string{"\"my/file.hpp\""};
        std::string parsed;
        // this assert fails, but I don't know why.
        assert(phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), header_name_quotes, space, parsed));
    }
}
```

Note that you need to match all chars except `"` in the second case, just as you did with `>` in the first.

Comment: Thanks. I was drawing from the C++17 working draft grammar. Indeed, there is both an h-char rule and a q-char rule. This silly oversight has been driving me crazy! In retrospect, I wish my question had been more substantial.

Answer (score 4):

Since you already have more answers than you can accept (:)) here's my $0.02:

```
template <typename Prefix, typename Postfix>
static auto quoted_(Prefix const& prefix, Postfix const& postfix) {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    return rule<struct _, std::string, true> {} = omit[prefix] >> *(char_ - postfix) >> omit[postfix];
}
```

Now you can write

```
auto header_name_brackets = quoted_('<', '>');
auto header_name_quotes   = quoted_('"');
```

The second assumes the obvious convenience overload.

### Another bug

In fact I think there's a bug that skips whitespace inside the delimiters. Fix it by adding `lexeme[]`:

```
template <typename Prefix, typename Postfix>
static auto quoted_(Prefix const& prefix, Postfix const& postfix) {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    return rule<struct _, std::string, true> {} = lexeme [ 
        omit[prefix] >> *(char_ - postfix) >> omit[postfix] 
    ];
}
```

### See full demo:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/075bc49384c3e3c0)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template <typename Prefix, typename Postfix>
static auto quoted_(Prefix const& prefix, Postfix const& postfix) {
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;
    return rule<struct _, std::string, true> {} = lexeme [ 
        omit[prefix] >> *(char_ - postfix) >> omit[postfix] 
    ];
}

template <typename Prefix>
static auto quoted_(Prefix const& prefix) { return quoted_(prefix, prefix); }

int main() {
    using boost::spirit::x3::space;

    auto header_name_brackets = quoted_('<', '>');
    auto header_name_quotes   = quoted_('"');

    {
        auto s = std::string{"<my/file.hpp>"};
        std::string parsed;
        assert(phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), header_name_brackets, space, parsed));
    }

    {
        auto s = std::string{"\"my/file.hpp\""};
        std::string parsed;
        assert(phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), header_name_quotes, space, parsed));
    }

    std::cout << "Bye\n";
}
```

Comment: Ha, very nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change this rule:

```
auto header_name_quotes   = '"' >> *(~char_('>')) >> '"';
```

to

```
auto header_name_quotes   = '"' >> *(~char_('\"')) >> '"';
```

Comment: Thanks! I wish I could accept more than one answer.